# Jeasyui Nested Grid UnselectAll

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-easyui

I've been implementing a nested grid using Jeasyui. How can I unselectAll grids that are highlighted including the sub-grids?

Thanks in advance,

Chris

[http://www.jeasyui.com/tutorial/datagrid/datagrid31_demo.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IwHKy.png)

Answer (score 0):

For example if you have the datagrid `ID` as `TestGrid`

```
 $('#TestGrid').datagrid("unselectAll");
```

Running this query any where within a jQuery script tag will do the needful.

Comment: This only applicable on the the first level of datagrid. The goal is on unselectAll including the subgrids.